# Django cannot serialize model.Decimal

Tags: python, django

When I write a Python/Django class like:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(..., max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

I get the following error when running `python manage.py makemigrations`:

> ValueError: Cannot serialize: Ellipsis
>
> There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
>
> For more, see 
>       https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing

If I exclude all decimal variables from all of my classes, then the above command runs successfully.

So, how does one include decimals in a way that is acceptable to Django?

Comment: replace `...` with `"FieldName"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to documentation two arguments are required for `DecimalField` that's are `max_digits` and `decimal_places`. You can check it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield).

To work with django you need to remove elipses from your class. You can use

```
models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

or

```
models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```